# jQuery: make get request to the same page with parameters

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, get

In my application, running in a PHP page, I want that a get request is done after a value from a select menu is chosen. The url of the page is

```
www.mydomain.it/admin/gest-prenotazioni-piazzola.php
```

So with a jQuery I would like to make a get request to the same page so that it is reloaded but with a parameter. In fact, at the beginning of the page I have:

```
if (isset($_GET["param1"])) {/*build page with content 1*/}
else if (isset($_GET["param2"])) {/*build page with content 2*/}
```

So I tried with

```
jQuery("#tipologia_piazzola").on('change', function() {
    if (this.value == "mensile") {
        jQuery.ajax({
          url: "",
          type: "get",
          data:{param1:"mensile"},
            success: function(response) {
            //Do Something
            },
            error: function(xhr) {
            //Do Something to handle error
            }
        });
    }

});
```

But this doesn't do exactly what I want because the call is done in background and the page is not reloaded. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks for reading

Comment: `@Lory Lory` i hope you get the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need ajax for this. All you need to do is:

```
$("#tipologia_piazzola").on('change', function() {
    window.location.href = window.location.href + '?param1=' + $(this).val();
});
```